# Replace img src with data-img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Found this solution and it's works, but this require TweenLite.js. 

It there any way to be working without TweenLite? and Compressing the code?

```js
$.fn.loadImg = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var t = $(this),
        e = t.data(),
        i = e.img;
      if (e.insert) {} else {
        var r = {
          backgroundImage: "url(" + i + ")"
        };
        TweenLite.set(t, r);
      }
    }), this;
}, (jQuery),
$(function() {
    $("[data-img]").loadImg();
});
```

Can anyone kindly tell me what wrong is with the following code, images are not displayed!

```js
$('figure data-img').each(function() {
  this.src = $(this).data('src');
});
```

```html
<figure data-img="photo1.jpg">  </figure>
<figure data-img="photo2.jpg">  </figure>
<figure data-img="photo3.jpg">  </figure>
```

Comment: The solution you posted as an edit is entirely unnecessary because correct solutions have been posted as answers already. So, yes, this can and should be done without TweenLite.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the figure tag has a src attribute, so:

```js
$("figure").each(function()
{

  $("img",this).attr("src",$(this).data("img"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure data-img="photo1.jpg"><img/>  </figure>
<figure data-img="photo2.jpg"><img/>  </figure>
<figure data-img="photo3.jpg"><img/>  </figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr function to change the attribute of div tag:

```
$('figure data-img').each(function() {
  this.src = $(this).data('src');
});
```

should be

```
$('figure data-img').each(function() {
 $(this).attr('data-img', 'src');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('figure').each(function() {
 $(this).attr('data-img','test.jpg');   
}
```

Comment: It would be ideal to add some description to this code and explain why/how it solves the question

Comment: I think it speaks for itself... even for a person who has 0 knowledge of coding.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. A person with 0 knowledge of coding may understand the code and what it does, but will not understand how or why you have done that (this is the description needed). In Stack Overflow, questions/answers with only code are considered as poor quality posts and they are listed to be reviewed and deleted (that's how I found your answer).

Comment: I cannot believe you're serious... you don't actually expect my to explain what a jQuery selector is to a person that already posted jQuery code, moreover, you can't expect me to explain my solution when it is almost identical to the problem he posted. The person who posted this question knows jQuery and the only difference between the problem and solution is the attr() function which he can *EASILY* look up on Google.
Kindly go harass somebody else!
EDIT: P.S. Thanks for discouraging people from helping on these forums the way you did.

Comment: @odedta Answers are for everyone who visits the question in future not just the original poster. Also this is being discussed on meta [Is it wrong to ask for a description of how/why the code works in code-only answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290231)

Comment: I understand that, as I mentioned before, the answer is self explanatory even for people with 0 knowledge in coding. I agree with your comment for more complicated answers though.

Answer (score -1):

There are two problems with your code. Crucially, the [figure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) does not have an `src` attribute. Your `figure` elements must each contain an `img` element in order to display the image. Secondly, your CSS selector should just be `'figure'`, you shouldn't include the data attribute.

```js
$('figure').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).data('src') + '">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure data-img="photo1.jpg"></figure>
<figure data-img="photo2.jpg"></figure>
<figure data-img="photo3.jpg"></figure>
```

If there are other `figure` elements that you do not want to apply this to, add a class to the appropriate elements to reference them by.